# masking/texture image help?

Tags: modeling, image, uv-image-editor, compositing-nodes

Ive uploaded this .Obj in blender but cant seem to edit away the edge of the image, ive tried doing it in the compositing but cant! see picture below.

Any help would be great!

[image]

so it looks like this
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove?

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth i want to remove the part exterior to the ruffled black line, i have updated the post to show image of what it should be like

Comment: I'd suggest an external application. Blender does have compositing masks, but they may not suffice.